# Non-parametric bootstrap not normal distributed

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

I am trying to derive the confidence intervals through bootstrap for some parameters I have calculated for a model via maximum likelihood estimation. I have also used profile likelihood to determine the CIs, but bootstrapped CIs is somewhat more reliable (at least that's what I have read).
My problem is, however, that when doing this, my parameter distributions look like this for 1000 resamples (three different parameters):
[image]

It's pretty obvious that there is not much normal distribution in none of them. But is it still okay to derive CIs from this (i.e. using the 2.5% from each side for a 95% CI), when it's that skewed ?

Comment: The method you describe is one standard as percentile bootstrap. I am not clear whether you imagine that bootstrapping is expected to yield  a normal distribution of estimates, as in general it is not. It's hard to say whether this is "okay" for any of your purposes. We would need to know much more about your model, its parameterisation and the data. The advice could include checking for outliers, considering a transformation of your variables, considering a different parameterisation, considering a quite different model just as plausibly as advice to proceed in the same direction.